# fftw/fftwtools and new fftw library

Tags: r, package, fftw

I found 2 packages in R which allow to compute fft via fftw library ("fastest in the west").
They are so old (by publish date in CRAN). Could I change version of fftw library using by these packages? Which files should I change? Is it possible in general?

I use MRO 3.2.5 and Windows 10.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by doing this? Your question is unclear.

Comment: These packages use same version of fftw library (really, 3.1.2). I want to force using them 3.3.4 version of fftw library. IS it possible?

Comment: Generally speaking packages will only specify *minimum* versions of packages they depend on, so if you have V3.3.4 of `fftw` installed they should be using that. Not sure why you are being so vague about the other two packages, but you should mention what they are in your question.

Comment: Yes, but there is no acceptable manual for windows installation. I thought that it's just libraries which links to the project...

Comment: Ok. I'll try again. So, I install MRO 3.2.5. I install fftw and fftwtools packages in it. This package use (as described) fftw library (http://www.fftw.org/). I didn't install fftw library directly, so, I think, fftw/fttwtools uses own dll form fftw library with earlier version of library. I want to renew this dll which these packages use (because of many new features in 3.3.4 version). But I don't know, how to do this. There is no installable distributive of fftw library from site (just only archive with dll's and same other files).

Comment: Okay that is much clearer. I haven't worked with MRO, but assuming your have proper credentials on the Windows machine you should be able download the source code for the R package, reconfigure it to point at your newer version of fftw, and build from source. The README in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/krahim/fftwtools) seems to hint at this. I believe you will need RTools installed on the Windows machine to do this.